# Does IAP TCP forwarding suffer from the TCP meltdown?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Let's assume I use IAP TCP forwarding for port 8080, which forwards port 8080 to my local workstation from the GCE VM. And let's assume that port is used for an HTTP connection.
Two questions:

- will this setup suffer from the TCP meltdown?

  - I'm going back and forth on this one, so having a definitive answer from a GCP specialist would be great.
- is the connection between IAP and VM encrypted in this specific case?

  - note that I'm not asking if the connection between my workstation and IAP is encrypted, I know it's, I'm asking about the "final" hop between the IAP and my VM.
  - at least based on the [diagrams](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tcp-forwarding-overview) and [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/security/encryption-in-transit) it should be automatically encrypted by GCP network BUT no "user" encryption (since HTTP)

    - related: would SSH (assuming OpenSSH) port forwarding of port 8080 over IAP SSH forwarding suffer from the TCP meltdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will this setup suffer from the TCP meltdown

IAP TCP forwarding doesn't use TCP-over-TCP. Instead, IAP TCP forwarding works on the application layer and encapsulates the HTTP/SSH/RDP/... data stream and forwards it over a WebSocket connection.

In your example, the protocol layers would be `HTTP > IAP > WebSocket > HTTP > TLS > TCP > IP`

> is the connection between IAP and VM encrypted in this specific case?

See [Encryption in Transit by Default](https://cloud.google.com/docs/security/encryption-in-transit#encryption_in_transit_by_default): GFE to VM traffic is protected by Google Cloud's virtual network encryption.

Comment: Thank you so much Johannes!! This is exactly what I needed to know. Is this documented anywhere in the GCP documentation?